# Laravel Eloquent returns 500 when I'm trying to put children in $with

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here is my Eloquent code:

```
class TestType extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['parent', 'children'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\TestType', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function children(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TestType', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Eloquent has children and parent which calls itself. This returns HTTP ERROR 500. It works as soon as I remove **children** from **$with**

It also works when I simply call it from like controller:

```
$testType = TestType::where('id', 1)->first();
return $testType->children;
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Step 1 on an internal server error, always, before you even ask anyone else: You go check the server’s error logs.

Comment: `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted ... \vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php on line 91`

Comment: @LevanTetemadze how many records do you have?

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz There are just one parent and one child in database. Everything's working without `$with` :(

Comment: this is maybe because you are using two relation on the same Model .. and as it process ..

Comment: @Demonyowh yes, you're right. Now I'm just trying to add `parent` or `children` in `$with` (parent has not another parent and child has not another child as well) like that in **__construct()** `$this->with[] = isset($this->parent_id) ? 'parent' : 'children';` but now `$this->parent_id` is always `NULL` in **__construct()** and I have no idea how to solve it :(

Comment: first of all my apologies for my bad english and i hope you understand what im going to explain .. let us say ModelName has been called .. _construct() will automatically run before anything else, thus the $this->parent_id is still null ..

Comment: Please accept the answer or post your answer to close the question thanks :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I call `with` from controller

`TestType::with(['children','parent'])->get();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want only children in your response then do this

```
$testType = TestType::with('children',function($query){
$query->where('id', 1);})->first();
```

Do check what you are getting using `dd()` and make sure you have specified relationships properly using foreign keys in migrations

I hope this will work if it doesn't feel free to shoot query. :)

Comment: No, this doesn't work. it worked when I removed `children` and `parent` from model and called it from controller like:`TestType::with(['children','parent'])->get();`

Comment: ok post your answer then to close it or should I update my answer to close your question?